# SSRS 2012 Different results between data tab and preview tab

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2012, reporting-services

I'm using SSRS 2012 with VS 2012 as the editing environment, against an MS SQL Server database. I have a text query dataset that when I execute in the Query dialog for the dataset returns proper results. In the preview tab, it returns nothing. If I replace the query text with a static list, it returns fine in both Query and preview.  With the real query, there are no errors returned from preview, just an empty result set. The report also operates properly when deployed to the server. This is repeatable with a very simple query, at first I thought it might be because the original query was fairly complicated.

The report was recently converted from 2005, and worked fine in that environment (SSRS 2005, using VS 2008 against the same database). This is the first report I'm digging into since the conversion, but a cursory look at other reports demonstrates similar symptoms, so I suspect that testing report changes is going to be very difficult until I can find out how to get around this.

This is NOT a caching issue, I have removed the .rdl.data several times with the same results.

Any ideas why preview is eating the data or what I can do to make it behave?

Comment: Check if the report is generating more than 1 page and first page is blank and data is on next page. Scroll to the right and to the bottom to see if you can find your data. It is difficult to troubleshoot without RDL. Generally such issues happen because of page width and margins.

Comment: @Anup Thanks for the suggestion, but the resulting record set is empty. All fields are returned as zero size.